# For the area and perimeter of a Triquetra, what is "a"?

Tags: geometry

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Triquetra.html

in three overlapping circles, similar to a vesica piscis, Wolfram claims the following two equations for perimeter and area:
$$perimeter = 3\pi a$$

$$area = \frac{1}{2}(2 \pi -\sqrt 3)a^2$$

Which are straight forward enough, except they don't explain what "a" is. I am guessing "a" is the distance from two intersections on any 'petal' of this 3 petaled leaf, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The parameter $a$ is the length of the radius.

Comment: radius of what? There's no circle, unless you mean any of the 3 circles used to form it?

Comment: Don't the circles have the same radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ is clearly intended to be the radius of the circles it is constructed from.  The distance between intersections is the radius of the circles.  Each arc of the circumference is $\frac 16$ of a circle, so the perimeter should be $2\pi a$.  I would send an e-mail alerting mathworld to the typo.  You could check the area calculation to confirm this or to alert them to a problem there as well.

Comment: They are including the inner arcs as part of what they mean by perimeter.

Comment: $3\pi a$ is the total length of the self-intersecting path of the traditional [triquetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra) "knot", which comprises nine arcs. (I'd still consider it a typo to call this the "perimeter", especially when showing a region.)

Comment: im glad you also noticed the weird notation for the inner/outer arcs. It threw me because i also counted 6 1/6th portions of a circle, or 1 circle, which should be pi x diameter or 2pi x radius.

Comment: @Tristian:  I think Blue has put his mouse on it.